# Apple GameKit EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have build the plugins and added to project but when I run game I am getting these errors

https://github.com/apple/unityplugins

EntryPointNotFoundException: AppleCore_GetRuntimeEnvironment assembly: type: member:(null)
Apple.Core.Availability.OnApplicationStart () (at Library/PackageCache/com.apple.unityplugin.core@d07a9d20344c/Runtime/Availability.cs:40)
EntryPointNotFoundException: GKLocalPlayer_GetLocal assembly: type: member:(null)

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdGpU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdOjm.jpg)

I tried run Game Center apple for unity I have build the plugin but not working dll